# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' python using spacy

Tags: python, spacy

Here is the full error message:

> AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        24 
>        25 # train
>   ---> 26 pipe.fit(train1, labelsTrain1)
>        27 
>        28 # test
>
> C:\Users\mcichonski\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.pyc
>   in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
>       246             This estimator
>       247         """
>   --> 248         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
>       249         if self._final_estimator is not None:
>       250             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
>
> C:\Users\mcichonski\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.pyc
>   in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
>       211                 Xt, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
>       212                     cloned_transformer, None, Xt, y,
>   --> 213                     **fit_params_steps[name])
>       214                 # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
>       215                 # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer
>
> C:\Users\mcichonski\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.pyc
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       360 
>       361     def **call**(self, *args, **kwargs):
>   --> 362         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
>       363 
>       364     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):
>
> C:\Users\mcichonski\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.pyc
>   in _fit_transform_one(transformer, weight, X, y, **fit_params)
>       579                        **fit_params):
>       580     if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
>   --> 581         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
>       582     else:
>       583         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
>
> C:\Users\mcichonski\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.pyc
>   in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
>       867 
>       868         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
>   --> 869                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
>       870 
>       871         if self.binary:
>
> C:\Users\mcichonski\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.pyc
>   in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
>       790         for doc in raw_documents:
>       791             feature_counter = {}
>   --> 792             for feature in analyze(doc):
>       793                 try:
>       794                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]
>
> C:\Users\mcichonski\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.pyc
>   in (doc)
>       264 
>       265             return lambda doc: self._word_ngrams(
>   --> 266                 tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
>       267 
>       268         else:
>
> C:\Users\mcichonski\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.pyc
>   in (x)
>       230 
>       231         if self.lowercase:
>   --> 232             return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
>       233         else:
>       234             return strip_accents
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Here is the code:

```
def printNMostInformative(vectorizer, clf, N):
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    coefs_with_fns = sorted(zip(clf.coef_[0], feature_names))
    topClass1 = coefs_with_fns[:N]
    topClass2 = coefs_with_fns[:-(N + 1):-1]
    print("Class 1 best: ")
    for feat in topClass1:
        print(feat)
    print("Class 2 best: ")
    for feat in topClass2:
        print(feat)

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizeText, ngram_range=(1,1))
clf = LinearSVC()

pipe = Pipeline([('cleanText', CleanTextTransformer()), ('vectorizer', vectorizer), ('clf', clf)])

# data
train1 = train['Title'].tolist()
labelsTrain1 = train['Conference'].tolist()

test1 = test['Title'].tolist()
labelsTest1 = test['Conference'].tolist()

# train
pipe.fit(train1, labelsTrain1)

# test
preds = pipe.predict(test1)
print("accuracy:", accuracy_score(labelsTest1, preds))
print("Top 10 features used to predict: ")

printNMostInformative(vectorizer, clf, 10)
pipe = Pipeline([('cleanText', CleanTextTransformer()), ('vectorizer', vectorizer)])
transform = pipe.fit_transform(train1, labelsTrain1)

vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(len(train1)):
    s = ""
    indexIntoVocab = transform.indices[transform.indptr[i]:transform.indptr[i+1]]
    numOccurences = transform.data[transform.indptr[i]:transform.indptr[i+1]]
    for idx, num in zip(indexIntoVocab, numOccurences):
        s += str((vocab[idx], num))
```

Looks like it has something to do with the train1 data.  Not sure how to fix this.

This is after cleaning the data ad now trying to use this function to print out the most important features, the features that have the highest coefficients:

Comment: Indent your function properly. Also currently I have to literally walk through the code to look for the keyword `lower`. Add more details where the error is coming from... and Voila! there is no `lower`

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Edit your question to include the full error message.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Full error message

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for more information - this is based off a Tutorial 
https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-for-text-classification-using-spacy-in-python-b276b4051a49. I was also getting the same error:

This is in relation to the `cleanText()` function which did not return anything for the pipeline to work with - Hence the NoneType Object traceback

```
def cleanText(text):
    text = text.strip().replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", " ")
    text = text.lower()
```

If you add `return text` it should fix your error

```
def cleanText(text):
    text = text.strip().replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", " ")
    text = text.lower()    
    return text
```